# What did Trump mean when he called Lincoln's legacy 'questionable'?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, civil-war, slavery

[So yesterday Trump said this:](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/06/12/trump-criticizes-lincoln-brags-he-has-done-a-lot-to-help-black-americans.html)

> I think I’ve done more for the black community than any other president. And let’s take a pass on Abraham Lincoln, because he did good, although it’s always questionable, you know, in other words, the end result.

This statement doesn't make sense to me. I know Trump wasn't talking about ending slavery when he said the 'end result' was 'questionable' because that would be going too far, even for Trump.

My best guess would be he meant the civil war. But the 'end result' was the Union winning the war and slavery ending nationwide.

I don't understand which 'end result' he is talking about. What is he trying to imply?

Comment: Welcome to Politics SE!  Unfortunately, this is a question that can only be answered by speculation, which means it's not a very good fit for this site.  Please take a moment to take the [tour] and read the [help] to learn about the kinds of questions we can accept, and if you can [edit] your question to make it work here, then please do so.

Comment: Simple.  Lincoln was an OK, pretty good, Prez.  Just not the bestest ever greatest A+ Prez.  Aside from that, unfortunately not answerable here.

Comment: @JoeC I think that this question might be answerable as it is.  Quite a few things that happened during Lincoln's Presidency have at best a questionable basis in the US Constitution. such as the [creation of the state of West Virginia from parts of the state of Virginia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Virginia_in_the_American_Civil_War) and [Lincoln's suspension of habeas corpus without Congressional approval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habeas_Corpus_Suspension_Act_(1863)).  There may be evidence somewhere that Trump is referring to acts such as those.

Comment: @Just Me: But the question isn't about Lincoln's (de)merits as a President, it's about Trump's opinion of Lincoln, which isn't really answerable unless he's supplied details.

Comment: Closers: Trump is a widely known public figure who has mentioned Lincoln many times.  It seems both possible and likely that there could be quite a bit of information available that might give us sufficient perspective on Trump's assessment of Lincoln to answer this Q.

Comment: While I certainly cannot say for *sure* that Trump thinks that the end result of the Civil War or the Emancipation Proclamation (i.e. the prohibition of chattel slavery) was a bad idea, Trump has a long history of expressing skepticism of Lincoln's legacy.  For instance,  he once said that "If you can believe it, Abraham Lincoln was treated supposedly very badly, but nobody's been treated badly like me."